# What's a suitable mount for an Ogre?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, mount

My players just managed to seriously anger an Ogre Mage who's leader of a couple of Ogre tribes.

I'm thinking about having some of the Ogres mounted though - the question is what would they ride?

I don't want to use dinosaurs (wrong part of the continent) or giant lizards in general (the Cave Giants are working with those). So what would be a suitable mount for an Ogre?

I'm thinking huge sized, quadruped...its almost tempting to +size a dire wolf or similar.

To be more specific, I'm looking for a creature that is:

- Huge Sized
- Quadruped
- Strong enough and with the right build to believably carry an Ogre

  - This is the problem with upsizing wolves, it might work but something bulkier might be more believable.
- Smart enough to ride/train (min int 2)
- Stupid enough to be a mount not a companion (max int 6)
- Not a lizard or dinosaur
- Fitting thematically with ogres

Comment: Read that as "Smart enough to ride a train" and failed my save against confusion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An up-sized Rhinoceros seems pretty fitting. Rhinos are tough and beefy, famously ill-tempered, short sighted and love charging into battle and running over everything that gets in their way.

Comment: Call it a 'Dire Rhino' and add a few superfluous horns, some armored bone plates... that's a wonderful idea.

Comment: The sheer awesomeness of a ogre mounted on a giant Rhinoceros is something that I have no words for. Have a +1!

Answer (score 13):

In Pathfinder, ogres are generally way too short-sighted to use animals or mounts of any kind - the temptation to kill, eat, and or mate with them from all the ogres daily means that slaves, animals, etc. don't last more than a couple days. (Classic Monsters Revisited).

None of the variant ogres in the Monster Codex have any kind of mount. The ogre antipaladin has a fiendish rhino as a summonable servant but it's too small to ride. That book notes that "These large brutes require tremendous amounts
of meat to survive, but have little patience for mundane
tasks such as agriculture or animal husbandry, so they fill
their larders by pillaging, robbing, and killing." The Kreegs in Rise of the Runelords, one of the definitive (and most successful, per CMR) groups of ogres have no mounts or animals of any kind either in their warband or lair. So you're pretty much headed out from any Pathfinder precedent with a mounted ogre.

There are two orc-kept war beasts in the book Belkzen, Hold of the Orc Hordes that are large enough to serve (Huge) and couple plausibly be given to the ogres - the Bull of Zagresh and the Warcat of Rull. Their stats are not on d20PFSRD yet, but doubtless will be soon. Nothing else in the first Giantslayer AP chapter or the surrounding books mentions any kind of mounted ogre.

If you're bound and determined to do it - they're more appropriate for giants, but [mammoths](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/elephant/elephant-mammoth) and [mastodons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/elephant/elephant-mastodon) are traditional giant-sized mounts. (There are other megafauna too, not sure if you group those in with "dinosaurs" in your mind or not.)

Answer (score 12):

Giant Degenerate Shaggra Ogres

If there's one thing Ogres like (besides rape, murder, and gluttony) it's incest.  Applying the Giant template to Degenerate Ogres fits with the theme of mutant powers the Ogres have going, and riding their family members makes the most sense of any mount from an Ogrish standpoint.

Your criteria in detail:

- Huge Sized

  - yep
- Quadruped

  - This is why we choose the Shaggra in specific.  They are quadrupedal.  You could also just throw it in as just another mutation the degenerates picked up, if you want to use a different variety.
- Strong enough and with the right build to believably carry an Ogre

  - Yes, this is a thing.  Ogres are very strong, certainly strong enough to carry another, smaller, ogre.  Giant quadrupedal Ogres can carry a ridiculous amount of weight RAW.  Ogres as evil mounts is also a fantasy trope, though usually they're mounts for Medium sized creatures.  Ogres also have a lot of experience mounting each other.  They should probably get a racial bonus to ride checks.
- Smart enough to ride/train (min int 2)

  - Ogres are real smart compared to most mounts
- Stupid enough to be a mount not a companion (max int 6)

  - Ogres are Int 6.  Really I think that means Int 3+ creatures should count as companions, but these are your requirements, not mine.  Degenerate ogres are "Utterly Psychotic", though, which might help make them less companionable to their riders.
- Not a lizard or dinosaur

  - Depends what their mommy mated with.  We're gonna guess it was an Ogre, though, so we're probably safe here.
- Fitting thematically with ogres

  - This is the big one.  Ogres only work with ogres, if their stomachs have anything to say about it.  So ogres ride ogres, and all the ogres are happy.

Answer (score 2):

In a Pathfinder set, ogres mainly live in patriarchal societies, and are used to the company of direwolves (or even, sometimes, worgs) as pets.

It is no more or more 'suitable', but it would be quite lore friendly to use upsized direwolves. Rules are very clear on how to upsize and existing creature. But don't worry, and just use your DM talent to make it fun and enjoyable for your players. You could sacrifice a bit of logic for a bunch of fun, depending on your mates preferences.